# Laning against AD bruiser Nidalee?

Tags: league-of-legends

Which champion(s) have a better chance of surviving lane against Nidalee? If you happen to not have these champions, how do you counter her?

I play her myself, so I know buying resistances is useless because she has so much sustained damage and poke with her no mana cost abilities.

Using someone like Yorick may work I suppose, but only if you have a lot of mana potions or mana regeneration runes.

How can I effectively lane against her without spending too many resources just to avoid being killed?

Comment: If you avoid taking too much damage pre-3, Riven does really well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're laning top lane Nidalee. Pantheon wins against her early and mid game, Xin Zhao is also considerably strong against her. That being said, Bruiser Nidalee really is a farm fest. If you play it properly, you shouldn't die against her at all, but you won't be able to kill her either.

Indications that you're laning vs an inexperienced bruiser Nidalee:

- She tries to full clear creeps with her full w->e->q combo in cat form

Punish this. If she tries to use her full combo for clear, remember that you have 4 seconds to punish her while she's in full cool-down.

- She's usually in cat form.

This means that she won't be able to harass you from afar. Remember, new cat form does not have extra move speed, so you should be able to punish her if she ever tries to clear wave. If she doesn't try to clear wave, feel free to push and force her to clear wave with her combo -> punish.

After the rework, while her execute damage is incredible, it's only useful if she harasses you enough to actually perform the execute. In other words, she will try to poke you down with autos rather than jump on you, as we used to do before the rework. After a couple of auto attacks (if you're at 75% health and the lanes are equal), she will not be afraid to use her full combo on you, which will bring you to about 30% health even without any damage items.

TL:DR Don't let her use her skills to farm without punishing her.

Comment: I tried very hard to avoid her skills and I did that successfully however I was olaf at the time so she still was able to just poke me down with nothing but aa cause she never landed any of her spears she also abused her heal and would take turret shots just to harress then heal back up i honestly couldnt even farm with my q in the lane because of this

Comment: Just slowly build up armor and those pokes won't do much anymore. If shes pushing, try to freeze lane the best you can and just wait for ganks from your jonglador. Don't stay too long and don't worry too much about losing turret.  More often than not, you can farm much more easily after you lose a turret because they won't extend past river.  If they do then its a free kill for your team if you can get them to rotate top.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that champions with strong early all-ins can lane fairly well against Nidalee.
So Wukong/Pantheon/Renekton/Rengar/Xin all can do really well against her.

You push for lvl 2 first, then all-in and force her to back early. With that time, you can take a lead in experience and cs, and use that to zone her out.

If you can force her to farm with her skills, then you can win further trades.

Remember that if you're allowing yourself to get poked down so far by autos, you're going to get wrecked by her execute damage. Consider picking up a dorans shield if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

If you're less willing to all in her, I've found good luck with Vlad. If you manage around the minion wave well, her poke should come in rarely enough that you can heal spears back, and also be able to heal up a couple of auto attacks per Q. Pool can dodge her cougar form all in (though mindful that the cast does % damage to you still), and E is extremely strong in extended fights and laning. If you can retaliate against her cougar form with your ult and E with max stacks, you can chunk her, farm the minion wave, and heal up some damage she did all at the same time.
It isn't the easiest time, but it's been a lot better for me than any other top laner I've played.